# Find specific number of a word from the beginning in string

Tags: arrays, string, find, c++-cli

I've been gathering information using api calls from my jira. Information gathered is saved in a body file and it has the following content:

No tickets:

```
{"startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":0,"issues":[]}{"startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":0,"issues":[]}
```

One Ticket:

```
{"expand":"names,schema","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":1,"issues":[{"expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields","id":"456881","self":"https://myjira...com","key":"TICKET-1111","fields":{"summary":"[TICKET] New Test jira","created":"2018-12-17T01:47:09.000-0800"}}]}{"expand":"names,schema","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":1,"issues":[{"expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields","id":"456881","self":"https://myjira...com","key":"TICKET-1111","fields":{"summary":"[TICKET] New Test jira","created":"2018-12-17T01:47:09.000-0800"}}]}
```

Two Tickets:

```
{expand:schema,names,startAt:0,maxResults:50,total:2,issues:[{expand:operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields,id:456881,self:https://myjira...com,key:TICKET-1111,fields:{summary:[TICKET] New Test jira,created:2018-12-17T01:47:09.000-0800}},{expand:operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields,id:320281,self:https://myjira...com,key:TICKET-2222,fields:{summary:[TICKET] Test jira,created:2016-03-18T07:58:52.000-0700}}]}{expand:schema,names,startAt:0,maxResults:50,total:2,issues:[{expand:operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields,id:456881,self:https://myjira...com,key:TICKET-1111,fields:{summary:[TICKET] New Test jira,created:2018-12-17T01:47:09.000-0800}},{expand:operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields,id:320281,self:https://myjira...com,key:TICKET-2222,fields:{summary:[TICKET] Test jira,created:2016-03-18T07:58:52.000-0700}}]}
```

etc..

Using this code I've been able to gather total open tickets:

```
std::ifstream t("BodyOpenIssues.out");
std::string BodyString((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
// Removing Quotes
BodyString.erase(std::remove(BodyString.begin(), BodyString.end(), '"'), BodyString.end());
int Result = 0;
unsigned first = BodyString.find("total:");
unsigned last = BodyString.find(",issues");
std::string TotalOpenIssues = BodyString.substr(first + 6, last - (first + 6));
Result = std::stoi(TotalOpenIssues);

return Result;
```

Using a second function I'm trying to get the keys based on total open tickets.

```
if (GetOpenIssuesNumber() > 0)
{
    std::ifstream t("BodyOpenIssues.out");
    std::string BodyString((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    // Removing Quotes
    BodyString.erase(std::remove(BodyString.begin(), BodyString.end(), '"'), BodyString.end());
    unsigned first = BodyString.find("key:TICKET-");
    unsigned last = BodyString.find(",fields");
    std::string TotalOpenIssues = BodyString.substr(first + 11, last - (first + 11));
    String^ Result = gcnew String(TotalOpenIssues.c_str());
    return "TICKET-" + Result;
}
else
{
    return "No open issues found";
}
```

What I mean is:
If Total is 1 to search from the beginning and find the first key TICKET-1111. 
If Total is 2 to search from the beginning and get the first key TICKET-1111 then to continue from there and to find the next key TICKET-2222. 
And based on that total to find that many keys in that string.

I got lost from all the casting between the types as ifstream reads the file and I save the result in std::string. After the find I save the result in System::String to use it in my Label.. I've been researching and found out that I can use char array but I can't make it dynamic based on BodyString.length().

If more information is required please let me know. 
Any suggestions are really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: These are formatted as JSON. You should use a JSON library for C++ and parse the files with that. Using search/replace is unnecessary complicated and you will likely run into corner cases you haven't considered sooner or later (do you really want the code to randomly miss tickets, etc.?). Also `String^` is not C++. Are you writing C++/CLI instead of C++? If so, please tag `c++-cli` instead of `c++`.

Comment: I'll check that right now. Yes I'm using c++-cli as I'm building simple UI program for the first time :) C++ was changed to c++-cli. Thank you walnut!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went for nlohmann json library. It has everything I need. Thank you Walnut!

> These are formatted as JSON. You should use a JSON library for C++ and parse the files with that. Using search/replace is unnecessary complicated and you will likely run into corner cases you haven't considered sooner or later (do you really want the code to randomly miss tickets, etc.?). Also String^ is not C++. Are you writing C++/CLI instead of C++? If so, please tag c++-cli instead of c++. – walnut